# need laravel regular expression pattern for index number validation

Tags: php, laravel

validating index_number with regular expression

i want the index number to start with 'UST' followed by 9 digits
example UST16280180

```
 'index_number'  => 'required|unique:students|min:11|max:11|regex:(UST)+{0-9}/i',
```

this is the results that i want : UST16280149

Comment: UST16280149 is UST plus 8 digits, do you want 8 or 9 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `regex` rule, case sensitive on `UST`:

```php
'index_number'  => 'regex:/^UST\d{9}$/',
```

This is for case insensitivity (it accepts `UST`, `ust`, `Ust` etc.):

```php
'index_number'  => 'regex:/^UST\d{9}$/i',
```

Change the `{9}` in the *regex* with the number of digits you want after `UST`, example for 8 digits:

```php
'index_number'  => 'regex:/^UST\d{8}$/',
```

Comment: thanks dparoli , it worked. sorry for delay in replying

Comment: Glad to be of help, please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).